# Efficent way of finding values that are within 1% of standard deviation of eachother

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a list of values, I want to delete all the values that are within one percent of the standard deviation of another value.

I currently have two nested for loops. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing it, perhaps using numpy and vectorization? 
My current, inefficient code.

```
# 1% of the std
std_range = np.std(values) / 100
# if value is in 1% of std, set to None
for idx, val in enumerate(values):
    for idx2, val2 in enumerate(values):
        if val is None or val2 is None:
            continue
        elif (val2 - std_range <= val <= val2 + std_range) and idx != idx2:
            values[idx] = None
# delete None values
values = list(filter(None, ml_results))
```

Comment: Can you provide an example values and expected result?

Comment: @NicoT For example [1,3,5,7,8,8.006], either 8 or 8.006 will be deleted, as they are within one percent of the standard deviation of each other.

Comment: Is the order of the elements in the array relevant? If not, you can sort elements and compare with the next/previous element

Comment: No the order does not matter. That is a good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that order is not relevant here is an aproach.

```
    std_range = np.std(values) / 100
    sorted_values = sorted(values)
    for id, val in enumerate(sorted_values[:-1]):
        next_value = sorted_values[id + 1]

        if val + std_range >= next_value:  # value is within range
            sorted_values[id] = None

    print(list(filter(None, sorted_values)))
```